# Why can't I read /dev/stdout with a text editor?

Tags: linux, files, stdout

I just started learning how *Everything Is A File*<sup>TM</sup> on Linux, which made me wonder what would happen if I literally read from /dev/stdout:

```
$ cat /dev/stdout 
^C
$ tail /dev/stdout 
^C
```

(The `^C` is me killing the program after it hangs).

When I try with `vim`, I get the unthinkable message: "/dev/stdout" is not a file.  Gasp!

So what gives, why am I getting hangups or error messages when I try to read these "files"?

Comment: What vim considers a file and what is meant by "everything is a file" (no associated trademark) in *nix are not the same thing.  See e.g. **[#1](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/197439/25985)** and **[#2](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/166686/25985)**.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> why am I getting hangups

You aren't getting "hangups" from `cat(1)` and `tail(1)`, they're just blocking on read.  `cat(1)` waits for input, and prints it as soon as it sees a complete line:

```
$ cat /dev/stdout
foo
foo
bar
bar
```

Here I typed `foo`<kbd>Enter</kbd>`bar`<kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>.

`tail(1)` waits for input, and prints it only when it can detect `EOF`:

```
$ tail /dev/stdout
foo
bar
foo
bar
```

Here I typed again `foo`<kbd>Enter</kbd>`bar`<kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>.

> or error messages

Vim is the only one that gives you an error.  It does that because it [runs](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/dce1a496bdb61784f2b725c754b90b613bef8bcb/src/fileio.c#L442) `stat(2)` against `/dev/stdout`, and it finds it doesn't have the `S_IFREG` bit set.

`/dev/stdout` is a file, but not a *regular* file.  In fact, there's some dance in the kernel to give it an entry in the filesystem.  On Linux:

```
$ ls -l /dev/stdout
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 May  8 19:42 /dev/stdout -> /proc/self/fd/1
```

On OpenBSD:

```
$ ls -l /dev/stdout
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel   22,   1 May  7 09:05:03 2015 /dev/stdout
```

On FreeBSD:

```
$ ls -l /dev/stdout
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  4 May  8 21:35 /dev/stdout -> fd/1

$ ls -l /dev/fd/1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel  0x18 May  8 21:35 /dev/fd/1
```

Answer (score 5):

(Almost) everything is a file but not everything is a *regular* file. It doesn't make sense to call a text editor on something that is a special file such as a directory, a network socket, a serial port, etc.

The file `/dev/stdout` can be one of several things depending on the unix variant:

- a “special” file, typically a character device;
- a “magic” symbolic link that points to the file that the process accessing it has open on this descriptor;
- a symbolic link to one of the above.

In any case, opening `/dev/stdout` and similar files creates a new file descriptor that's associated with the same file that the application already has open on file descriptor 1. “Standard output” means file descriptor 1, and it's only a convention that this file descriptor is used for output — the kernel doesn't care.

When you run a program in a terminal, all three standard descriptors (0 = standard input, 1 = standard output, 2 = standard error) are opened on the terminal device. Reading from that device returns characters typed by the user, and writing to that device displays text in the terminal window. (There's no standard way, given a terminal device, to read the output that it displays or to inject input into it.)

When you run `cat /dev/stdout`, that does exactly the same thing as `cat /dev/stdin` or `cat /dev/stderr`, because these three file descriptors are connected to the same file: it tells `cat` to read from the terminal. That's what `cat` with no argument does too.

If you ran `cat /dev/stdout >foo`, then `/dev/stdout` would refer to the file `foo` — that command is equivalent to `cat foo >foo`. Depending on the `cat` implementation, it might either error out (the GNU version complains that “input file is output file”), or it might do nothing because it reads from the file `foo` which is empty (`>foo` just truncated it). With a version of `cat` that doesn't detect this special case, if `foo` is not empty, then `cat /dev/stdout >>foo` or the equivalent `cat foo >>foo` would append the content of the file to itself indefinitely.

When you run `vim /dev/stdout`, it complains because it doesn't know how to edit a terminal (that just doesn't make sense).

Answer (score 2):

`cat` and `tail` are looking for optional content followed by an end of file. `/dev/stdout` remains open, so `cat` and `tail` just keep looking.

Answer (score -5):

please try these

```bsh
sudo su
chmod +x /dev/stdout
chmod +x /dev/stderr
exit su
```

I tried and worked  and  you will learn by trying :)

I don't know why it's necessary?  explain it anybody?

[image: stdout permissions info]
[image: stdin permissions info]
[image: MY GOAL HAPPY OF THE END]

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Brevity vs. fuller explanations are irrelevant when an answer is completely devoid of anything related to the question at hand. There's no reason whatsoever that adding the execute permission to `/dev/stdout` and others would matter. Also, there's no such thing as `/dev/stderror`, and `exit` doesn't take string argument (just a number).

Comment: @Kusalananda
Thanks, but I have been same problem with question owner and I fix this way
Also
 `echo 'something' > /dev/stdout`
` /dev/stdout permission denied error`, solved this way on me

Comment: @Master_n_Master `echo 'something' >/dev/stdout` doesn't make sense.  `echo` is already writing to standard output without the redirection.

Comment: @Kusalananda
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38538/bash-dev-stderr-permission-denied
in here, in me too, it had.
I will test again, when reboot live linux! 
Because I  had  seen same error

Comment: Note that the solution in that question is to remove the redirection to `/dev/stdout`, which shouldn't have been there from the start anyway.

Comment: False and False Badges